# Streamlit: Fix st.form to the bottom of the st.container

Tags: python, streamlit

I have a `st.form` that includes a `st.text_input` and a `st.form_submit_button`. The form is embedded as part of the `st.container`, and I want to keep it at the bottom of the page as the input field for a GPT model (similar to that of ChatGPT).

Here is a simplified example of my current code:

```py
import streamlit as st

with st.container():
    with st.form("input_form"):
        col1, col2 = st.columns([9, 1])

        with col1:
            st.text_input("Please enter what you want to tell me here: ")

        with col2:
            st.form_submit_button()
```

Note that `st.chat_input` is not an option for me since it doesn't allow custom starter prompt.

I tried to add the following CSS code:

```css
div[data-testid="stForm"] {
    /* Select the st.form */
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

But the end result isn't pretty (see the images below).

This is `st.form` before adding the CSS code:

[image]

This is `st.form` afterward:

[image]